# Screen height being reduced

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, uikit

I have been developing an iOS app with no problems using xCode interface builder and storyboard. Everything has been going great until I opened my project today and now every screen is displaying incorrectly!!

For some reason it seems to be reducing the height of all screens.. It happens on all iPhone sizes..

[image]

Comment: Select Your Navigation Controller In StoryBoard and goto the attribute Inspector set simulated matrics (size, topbar, bottom bar) =  Inferred.

Comment: @SAXENA_RAHUL It is already set to inferred, And it happens across all storyboard so I don't think its to do with the NavigationController

Comment: You must add (Default-568h@2x.png) splash image in your project goto (show issue navigator) left side of Xcode and click the validate project setting then ok it automatic add in your project.